Is there any philosophical significance to the superexponential bound for Presburger Arithmetic?
Presburger Arithmetic is, roughly, the additive theory of the natural numbers.  The  Fischer-Rabin theorem asserts a superexponential lower bound e^{e^{cn}} for the worst-case scenario for the length of a proof of a theorem of length n.  The constant c appearing in the estimate is positive but nothing else seems to be known about it.  It was discussed here.
Gaifman claims in

THE REVIEW OF SYMBOLIC LOGIC, Volume 5, Number 3, September 2012, ON ONTOLOGY AND REALISM IN MATHEMATICS,
HAIM GAIFMAN

that the Fischer-Rabin theorem has philosophical consequences.  Namely, Gaifman claims that

"if our resources restrict us to less than super-exponential computation, then some truths must remain unknown. ... the answers to some simple mathematical questions—for example, that some Diophantine equations have no solution—are beyond what we can know; and this is due to our epistemic limitations."

Gaifman appears to derive such a consequence from both incompleteness and Fischer-Rabin.  But I fail to see how one could derive such philosophical consequences without an explicit lower bound for the constant c.  Indeed, statements of interest to human beings have a uniform upper bound on length, say 1000000.  If the constant c is small enough, the superexponential bound of the Fischer-Rabin estimate may not provide any practical limitation on the length of a proof of statements of interest to human beings.  How could Gaifman justify drawing philosophical consequences from the Fischer-Rabin estimate?

Gaifman (page 500) uses 2^{2^{cn}} where n is the lenght of a formula. If we consider a formula written with 100 symbols (in formal languages, withou abbreviations, formulas grow quite quickly) we have that, with e.g. c=0.5, 2^50 is about 10^16 that is quite huge. And then the result is used as exponent for 2 again...

True, but what if c=0.0000000000005 instead?  @MauroALLEGRANZA

Having said that, IMO there is no real advantage, from a philosophical point of view, in using such a technical result in the discussion about Finitism: for sure, we are limited being (but electronic computer power is growing very fast) but still the objection to Finitism stand: write the biggest natural number that you can imagine... and then add 1.

Dummett has an answer to that objection: it depends on what kind of presentation one is allowed to use for natural numbers.  The argument you mentioned is not as strong as it superficially appears to be.  At any rate, Gaifman is not arguing for finitism here.
On the contrary, he argues for realism.  @MauroALLEGRANZA

"there is a constant c>0, such that ...there is an integer n0, so that for every n > n0 there is a theorem of PRS of length n whose shortest proof is longer than..." It says that for every n great enough we can find a theorem that is "practically impossible" to prove. If c is little, consider an n that is equal to 100c  and we still have 2^{2^{100}}. For what is worth...

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I addressed that point when I wrote that there is a uniform upper bound on the length of theorems that human beings can be possibly interested in.  For example, if it takes a lifetime to scan the statement of the theorem, that leaves little time for evaluating it :-)

Gaifman’s point is conceptual rather than practical who's not primarily concerned with specific statements humans might investigate but rather with the theoretical limitation the bound places on our epistemic abilities by complexity in addition to uncomputability from incompleteness or undecidability, and his Diophantine equation example above incidentally show that c won't be very small as you suggested and you could further search papers for c's best lower bound estimate. Also maybe future interest will focus on some extremely long conjecture like the Godel sentence or Goodstein sequence...

"Gaifman’s point is conceptual rather than practical who's not primarily concerned with specific statements humans might investigate but rather with the theoretical limitation" : This is an interesting idea, but if his conceptual and theoretical point means the availability of a computer with unlimited computing power then there is little difference between linear growth, super-exponential growth, or super-duper-exponential growth.  So I am still not sure what point he could possibly make here without an explicit lower bound for c.  I haven't seen such lower bounds in the literature. @Double

My "conceptual" here is not your "conceptual and theoretical", it's certainly not theoretical with a Turing machine, as then complexity with P=NP doesn't matter any more. My conceptual point is that one day we may form an extremely long Presburg Arithmetic conjecture, even if c is not very large (I've conjectured above that it cannot be very small, contrary to your hypothetical example), with limited resources we may not able to epistemically prove it or its negation, though we know Presburg Arithmetic is decidable, which is consistent with the transcendental knowledge of truth doctrine...

It would be interesting to see whether there are explicit lower bounds for c.  I posted the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4994818/explicit-bound-for-superexponential-estimate-for-presburger-arithmetic
